# Difference in tab behaviour for system python vs conda python

Tags: python, python-2.7, conda

My system python is at /usr/bin/python and the version is 2.7.10. My conda python version is 2.7.13. The difference in behaviour is how both the interpreters respond to a TAB. The system python interprets it as a regular TAB, but my conda python responds by showing me the contents of the directory.

Any help regarding how this can be solved would be great!